# How to convert string to boolean in this Powershell code for Exchange Online?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

My code is:

```
Import-Csv "$env:userprofile\Desktop\ExternalContacts.csv"| foreach {New-MailContact -Name $_.Name -DisplayName $_.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName | Set-MailContact -Identity $_.Name -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $_.HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled}
```

And I am getting:

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean", parameters of this type only accept booleans or numbers, use $true, $false, 1 or 0 instead.

Here are the first two rows of my CSV file as viewed in Notepad:

`Name,FirstName,LastName,ExternalEmailAddress,HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled`
`Ted Testington,Ted,Testington,ted.testington@blah.com,$true`

How can I do the necessary conversion?

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484682/safely-converting-string-to-bool-in-powershell

Answer (score 8):

Be careful with `-as`. It only works when a string is `0` or `1`.

Both `("FALSE") -as [bool]` and `[bool]("FALSE")`  will return `True`!

It's better to use

```
[System.Convert]::ToBoolean("FALSE")
[System.Convert]::ToBoolean("False")
[System.Convert]::ToBoolean(0)
```

Or Parse

```
[bool]::Parse("FALSE")
[bool]::TryParse("FALSE", $outputVariable) # Will not raise an exception if the parse fails
```

`Parse` only works with strings as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `-as` operator

```
-HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled ($_.HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled -as [bool])
```

Comment: Thanks. That gives: `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.