# Safely converting string to bool in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, boolean, tryparse

I'm trying to convert an argument of my PowerShell script to a boolean value. This line

```
[System.Convert]::ToBoolean($a)
```

works fine as long as I use valid values such as "true" or "false", but when an invalid value, such as "bla" or "" is passed, an error is returned. I need something akin to TryParse, that would just set the value to false if the input value is invalid and return a boolean indicating conversion success or failure.
For the record, I tried [boolean]::TryParse and [bool]::TryParse, PowerShell doesn't seem to recognize it.

Right now I'm having to clumsily handle this by having two extra if statements.

What surprised me that none of the how-to's and blog posts I've found so far deal with invalid values.
Am I missing something or are the PowerShell kids simply too cool for input validation?

Comment: You can specify parameter types in your script arguments, like `[bool]$something`. This way data types will be validated before your script even starts working.

Comment: Powershell has all kinds of options for validating parameter input so that you don't have to do it your self. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx Powershell will even generate good enough localized error messages for you. This info gets used in the get-help command too.

Comment: Have you considered using a `[switch]` parameter? See the Switch Parameter section in [`Get-Help about_Functions`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113231).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use a try / catch block:

```powershell
$a = "bla"
try {
  $result = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($a) 
} catch [FormatException] {
  $result = $false
}
```

Gives:

```powershell
> $result
False
```

Answer (score 34):

`TryParse` should work as long as you use `ref` and declare the variable first:

```powershell
$out = $null
if ([bool]::TryParse($a, [ref]$out)) {
    # parsed to a boolean
    Write-Host "Value: $out"
} else {
    Write-Host "Input is not boolean: $a"
}
```

Comment: This is IMHO the best solution. No try/catch-block needed.

Answer (score 10):

```
$a = 'bla'
$a = ($a -eq [bool]::TrueString).tostring()
$a

False
```

Comment: This is because PowerShell will convert any string greater than 0 characters to a Boolean ‘true’, behaviour which is consistent across other programming languages.

Comment: What if $a = "true" or $a = "True".  I assume only one of them would work.  I lean towards the TryParse approach.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use the switch statemement and only evaluate `True`, `1` and `default`:

```
$a = "Bla"
$ret = switch ($a) { {$_ -eq 1 -or $_ -eq  "True"}{$True} default{$false}}
```

In this if the string equals to `True` `$true` is returned. In all other cases `$false` is returned.

And another way to do it is this:

```
@{$true="True";$false="False"}[$a -eq "True" -or $a -eq 1]
```

Source [Ternary operator in PowerShell by Jon Friesen](http://jonfriesen.ca/ternary-operator-in-powershell/)

Comment: I just used this to include integer and string values.. ``Function ParseBool{
    [CmdletBinding()]
 param(
  [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [System.String]$inputVal
    )
    switch -regex ($inputVal) {
        "^1$|^true$" {$true}
        default{$false}
    }
}``

Answer (score 3):

just looked for this again and found my own answer - but as a comment so adding as an answer with a few corrections / other input values and also a pester test to verify it works as expected:

```
Function ParseBool{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [System.String]$inputVal
    )
    switch -regex ($inputVal.Trim())
    {
        "^(1|true|yes|on|enabled)$" { $true }

        default { $false }
    }
}

Describe "ParseBool Testing" {
    $testcases = @(
        @{ TestValue = '1'; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = ' true'; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = 'true '; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = 'true'; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = 'True'; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = 'yes'; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = 'Yes'; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = 'on'; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = 'On'; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = 'enabled'; Expected = $true },
        @{ TestValue = 'Enabled'; Expected = $true },

        @{ TestValue = $null; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = ''; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = '0'; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = ' false'; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = 'false '; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = 'false'; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = 'False'; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = 'no'; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = 'No'; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = 'off'; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = 'Off'; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = 'disabled'; Expected = $false },
        @{ TestValue = 'Disabled'; Expected = $false }
    )


    It 'input <TestValue> parses as <Expected>' -TestCases $testCases {
        param ($TestValue, $Expected)
        ParseBool $TestValue | Should Be $Expected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Prior answers are more complete, but if you know that `$foo -eq 1, "1", 0, "0", $true, $false...` anything that can be coerced to an `[int]`

Either of the following `statements` work:

```
[System.Convert]::ToBoolean([int]$foo)
[System.Convert]::ToBoolean(0 + $foo)
```

Hope that helps someone that just needs a simple solution.