# Convert string value "$false" to boolean variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

## Reason I'm Doing This

I'm trying to set a token in a file I have. The contents of the token is 1 line in the file, and it's string value is `$token=$false`

## Simplified to test code

When I try to convert this token into a bool value, I'm having some problems. So I wrote test code and found I'm not able to convert the string to a bool value.

```
[String]$strValue = "$false"
[Bool]$boolValue = $strValue

Write-Host '$boolValue =' $boolValue
```

This gives the following error...

```
Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean", parameters of this type only accept booleans or numbers, use $true, $false, 1 or 0 instead.
At :line:2 char:17
+   [Bool]$boolValue <<<<  = $strValue
```

As you can see, I am using the `$false` value as is suggested by the error message, but it's not accepting it. Any ideas?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484682/safely-converting-string-to-bool-in-powershell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PowerShell, the usual escape character is the backtick. Normal strings are interpolated: the `$` symbol is understood and parsed by PowerShell.  You need to escape the `$` to prevent interpolation.  This should work for you:

```
[String]$strValue = "`$false"
```

To convert "$true" or "$false" to a boolean in a generic way, you must first drop the leading `$`:

```
$strValue = $strValue.Substring(1)
```

Then convert to boolean:

```
[Boolean]$boolValue = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($strValue)
```

Using your code from your comment, the shortest solution would be:

```
$AD_Export_TokenFromConfigFile =
   [System.Convert]::ToBoolean(Get-Content $AD_Export_ConfigFile
                               | % {
                                      If($_ -match "SearchUsersInfoInAD_ConfigToken=") {
                                          ($_ -replace '*SearchUsersInfoInAD_ConfigToken*=','').Trim()
                                      }
                                   }.Substring(1))
```

Comment: Problem is this is assigning it as true. It should be false because that is what the string reads as. Maybe I should just add another if/else statement to handle it. But I would think I wouldn't have to.

Comment: I tried parsing "false" as a boolean, but no luck and same result. The bool is used for a token in a complex design I am writing. So It is preferred. Otherwise instead of just saying `$tokenInUse`, I would have to write `$tokenInUse -eq 'false'` in multiple if statements, for and while loops. I try to keep my code as clean as possible.

Comment: Note: the entire line looks like this `$AD_Export_TokenFromConfigFile = Get-Content $AD_Export_ConfigFile | % {If($_ -match "SearchUsersInfoInAD_ConfigToken=") {($_ -replace '*SearchUsersInfoInAD_ConfigToken*=','').Trim()}}`. This gets the value of `$true` or `$false` as a string. I'm just trying to cast it to a bool, but it always casts as true...

Comment: ah I see, I can easily just as well right `[String]$strValue = "false"` and then `[Bool]$boolValue = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($strValue)`. I didn't know to convert (using the system.convert method), the `$` must not be included. Thanks :) It would be nice if they updated that error message to ensure programmers did not include the `$` in their system.conversion method.

Comment: You could also do the following with `[bool]`: `[bool]::Parse($strValue)`