# Create user with "password never expires" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

I want to create a lot of users in my AD with a CSV file and a PowerShell script, but I don't find how to create a user with the argument "PasswordNeverExpire" and "user is active/inactive".

My CSV:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could create the account and use the following

```
Set-ADUser -Identity <name> -PasswordNeverExpires $true
```

this will set the account's password to never expire, if you're using a loop to create the account you can add that into it.

Comment: Note that you need to pass a boolean argument to the parameter. Since the values from the CSV are all strings, you need to [convert them to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29560200/1630171) first.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution which has worked for me is this way:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "passwd123" –AsPlainText –Force
$user = "userxyz"
New-ADUser -Name $user -AccountPassword $password
Set-ADUser $user -PasswordNeverExpires $true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process each row in the CSV (myCSV.csv in this example) as an object in PowerShell. During that process, you can manipulate each column (a property) value to fit your command. You can use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) to make things more readable and manageable.

```
Import-Csv MyCSV.csv | Foreach-Object {
    $Params = @{
        GivenName = $_.firstname
        Surname = $_.lastname
        SamAccountName = $_.username
        AccountPassword = $_.password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        Enabled = [bool]$_.enable
        PasswordNeverExpires = [bool]$_.PasswordNeverExpires
        Name = "{0} {1}" -f $_.firstname,$_.lastname
        Path = $_.ou
    }
    if ([bool]$_.AccountNeverExpires -eq $False) {
        $Params.Add(AccountExpirationDate,(Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 1 -Day 1))
    }
    New-ADUser @Params
}
```

**Considerations:**

- You may want to finely control `UserPrincipalName`. If so, you can simply add it to the `$Params` hash table with your preferred format.
- `-Name` is a required parameter. So I've added it to the hash table. I used the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#format-operator--f) (`-f`) to format the string. You can format it as desired.
- You have `AccountNeverExpires` set to `False` for a number of your entries. This means you will need to pass the parameter `-AccountExpirationDate` a valid `[datetime]` object. I used `January 1, 2020` in the example. Please update this to something appropriate.
- The `*-ADUser` commands that support a password parameter expect secure strings. This means you will need to convert plain text passwords before passing them to those parameters.
- `True` and `False` values read from a CSV file are read as strings. The `*-ADUser` commands expect those values to be `Boolean` type. In those cases, I used the `[bool]` type accelerator to cast those values to `Boolean`.